# WxWidgets 3.0.3 Bakefile samples prints contradictory error messages with different Bakefile versions

Tags: wxwidgets, bakefile

I'm on OSX 10.12.4, and there seems to be an existing system installation of `WxWidgets 3.0.2` as well as `bakefile 0.2.10`.

I didn't want to touch the system installed WxWidgets so I downloaded the tarball for WxWidgets 3.0.3, ran `configure --preset=/somelocalfolder && make install`.

I want to set up a Bakefile for a simple WxWidgets project that works on all platforms. I read `bakefile_quickstart.txt`, and decided to try and generate build files from `build/bakefiles/wxpresets/sample/minimal.bkl`

Running `bakefile -f gnu minimal.bkl` gave me the following error:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
This file cannot be processed with Bakefile version older than 0.2.2.
You are using Bakefile version 0.2.10. Please install the newest version
from http://www.bakefile.org.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/local/share/bakefile/presets/wx.bkl:113: error: Bakefile not new enough
    included from /Users/prashanthcr/code/wxWidgets-3.0.3/build/bakefiles/wxpresets/sample/minimal.bkl:5
```

This error message doesn't make sense since I believe `version 0.2.10` is greater than `version 0.2.2`.

I decided to download the newest version of Bakefile, `version 1.2.5.1`.

The command line flags and binary name seem to have changed completely, so I just tried the following:

`bkl minimal.bkl`

This gives me the error:

```
sample/minimal.bkl: error: this file is incompatible with new Bakefile versions; please use Bakefile 0.2.x to process it
```

The two error messages contradict each other and I don't know what to do.

Comment: @PashanthChandra, why do you want to use Bakefile for you own project? What they do is generate Makefile's and MSVC solutions. You will still need to build the project. The official and recommended way is to copy the sample (minimal or otherwise) to some directory and start developing. Or even install an IDE (CodeBlocks, CodeLite, Xcode, MSVC) and work with it.

Comment: I started developing a basic application on my Mac using [this Makefile](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Makefile). I wanted to be able to build this on Windows as well but I couldn't find a Makefile/vcproj files for it, and the quickstart gave me the impression that Bakefile could be used to generate both Windows and unix Makefiles for my project.

Comment: in the <wxWidgets>/samples/minimal everything is alrady generated. In Windows just copy that folder somewhere and compile using either MSVC or MinGW/gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed confusing, but let me try to explain: wxWidgets uses the old 0.x legacy bakefile branch. Bakefile 1.x is incompatible with it and can't be used with wxWidgets bakefiles. If you want to use bakefile for your own projects, please do use 1.x however as it's much better and simpler to use than 0.x.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying that. However that doesn't explain why I couldn't run the `minimal.bkl` sample using `bakefile 0.2.10`.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, I think there might be a problem with comparing `.9` and `.10` in bakefile 0.x code.